# Need to add two columns one being from previous row displayed using repeater on row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have two columns A and B , Both the columns are being calculated , i need to calculate B on base of diagonal addition. B1=A1, B2=B1+A2 , B3=B2+A3. etc..

Kindly help me out how to create.. 
i have two options either edit it in SSRS or in Procedure where the dataset is generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Diagonal addition" is an interesting term for what is commonly called a "cumulative sum".  You can do this calculation in SQL Server 2012 and onwards by doing:

```
select A, sum(A) over (order by id)
from table t;
```

In earlier versions:

```
select A,
       (select sum(t2.A) from table t2 where t2.id <= t.id) as B
from table t;
```

Note that both of these use a column called `id`.  This could be any column that specifies the ordering of the rows in the table.  Tables in SQL (in general) and SQL Server (in particular) are unordered sets.  So there is no concept of "previous" row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Thanks that did work/ but that is easy to use when we have specified table, what if i have to refer to the column which i have derived using many queries and joins. i know one way can be i'll have to use a temporary table, but can there be any other way out?

Comment: @user3640136 . . . You can use a CTE to define a table alias that can be used multiple times.  Or, upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server and use the built-in cumulative sum syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it's better to use joins instead of sub-queries, but version of Gordon Linoff will work great too!

```
SELECT a1.SumAmt as A, SUM(b1.SumAmt) as B
FROM Table1 a1
INNER JOIN Table1 b1 on a1.ID >= b1.ID
GROUP BY a1.ID, a1.SumAmt
ORDER BY a1.ID
```